# not able to upload file on remote server

Tags: php

I am trying to upload image file from my one server to another remote server (owned by me). but its giving me error

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(http://www.mysite.org/photo/color-sample-colorize12-10-2010-09-14-09.jpg) 
[function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections.
```

Thanks for any suggestion or help in advance

Comment: Do you have any idea how HTTP works? Well?

Comment: Have a look at a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244752/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-files-from-one-server-to-another-with-php

Comment: @amphetamachine however I am agree with you - a programmer have to distinguish a local filesystem from a remote daemon, but PHP developers doing nearly everything to hide this difference from usual programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that.... You need the sites to be on the same physical server and have the directory youre moving to have the proper permissions and be mapped in to both sites.

You could however use ftp or cURL functions to actually upload the file to the remote server, just not `move_uploaded_file`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the file from the remote server using something like [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and then save it to a file on the local server using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), or ftp, or curl if you have the permissions. You can't just copy a file like you would if it was on the same server. (I assume this is what you're trying to do, right?)

Comment: thanks cambraca.. i used FTp to upload files to remote server using scripting